# How to setup user authentication on a Squid caching server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, authentication, squid, ntlm

i've got Squid-2.7 running on our Windows 2008 box. Works great. I wish to restrict access to it via username restriction.

Currently, my username is BlahDomain\FooUser . Password: blah.

Is there any way i can tell Squid that user BlahDomain\FooUser is allowed to access all websites, provided they authenticate. Now, i'm assuming they need to authenticate with .. the AD, if the username is Domain\User?

I do NOT want to add things to the AD settings (eg. users into groups, etc.)

I wish to only do all configuration stuff on this local windows box where Squid is running.

Any help / suggestions?

I was thinking ntlm authentication, but I have no idea if this is possible with what I wish to do, above.

cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use ntlm auth with proper ordered acls on the squid proxy. You might see [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/squid-ntlm-authentication-configuration-howto/) and [this one](http://www.opensourcehowto.org/how-to/squid/squid-with-ntlm-authentication.html) to help you out with the setup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had a look at both those articles and i can't see how i restrict users by domain\name? ... ???

Comment: Seems like the only way to go is with groups or ip adresses, i can't find something answering fully your question. Sorry.

Comment: @Max: I ended up using Ip address restrictions. It works great :)